# Most computationally efficient method to insert into an ordered array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance

I have an array of arrays containing time-series data as follows:

```
var timeseries = [
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 3, 2],
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 1.2, 3],
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 02:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 4, 2]
]
```

The first item in the nested array is a javascript date.

I have a second array which contains a list of unique javascript dates, but that may or may not already exist in the *timeseries* array:

```
var newTimes = [
    Tue Dec 31 2013 00:13:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 
    Tue Dec 31 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 
    Tue Dec 31 2013 01:40:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
]
```

For each item in the *newTimes* array, I need to check whether that date exists in the arrays stored with the *timeseries* array. If it does not, I would like to insert a new array in the correct place (chronological order) into the timeseries array, and - crucially - copy the other array values from the directly preceding array. For example, combining the two above array as described would yeild:

```
var newTimeseries = [
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 3, 2],
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 00:13:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 3, 2],
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 1.2, 3],
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 01:40:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 1.2, 3],
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 02:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 4, 2]
]
```

I should note both arrays are already sorted. Also, items in *newTimes* will exist within the range of *timeseries*. Finally, the original *timeseries* array has an entry every hour, on the hour.

I have tried a couple of different methods but I am interested in the computationally most efficient approach. I am happy to use any appropriate well adopted third party libraries such as underscore.js if helpful.

Comment: A linked list comes to mind...

Comment: Well, a linked list would give you `O(1)` complexity for insertions and `O(n)` for searching. I think you'll find that "most efficient" is going to depend on how often you get a hit/miss.

Comment: Depending on the list size, you could probably insert everything, then transverse the list once to either copy the extra data or remove the double entries. Just brainstorming here :)

Comment: Storing unix timestamps instead of a date objects in your array i guess will help speed it up (when it comes to looking up the correct position to insert)

Comment: The list will vary in size. Usual use case range might be 150 entries, up to about 4000

Comment: @techfoobar Sure, can easily store timestamps; I'm already using Moment.js for most date work after the fact anyway.

Comment: @jtromans - Binary search is your friend.

Comment: @techfoobar What about loopnig over the larger timeseries array and comparing each item in turn to the newTimes[0] entry and splicing away that entry when finished?

Comment: Your arrays are already sorted? Bubble sorting insert would give you O(n), and that's probably the best you can squeeze out of a dense array. That's all theory, though.

Comment: @jtromans - The problem is that (in the worst case), if `newTimes[0]` happens to be at the end of (or bigger than the last item in) `timeSeries` array, then it would take a minimum of N iterations (N being the size of `timeSeries` array). Same goes for every item in `newTimes[0]`. Binary searching will reduce this dramatically.

Comment: @techfoobar newTimes[0] is already sorted so it wouldn't need to start over upon inserting, it would just carry on. Also, dates in newTimes are guaranteed to be within the range of timeseries.

Comment: @jtromans - Ex: in the above case, if size of `timeSeries` is `150`, `newTimes[0]` will need `150` iterations to be resolved. Binary search will need a maximum of `7` iterations (worst case).

Comment: Ok, still to match the first item - `newTimes[0]` - iterations can be considerably reduced if using binary search.

Comment: Good point, then I could loop through once the first item is matched

Comment: My solution is posted as an answer below. I think this is the best approach, as opposed to using a Binary Search to get the initial offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having considered a Binary Search (suggested by techfoobar in the comments), and the Bubble Sort (friendzis), the most optimal solution I have come up with so far is following this logic.

As opposed to using a Binary Search, consider the following.

Because we know that both arrays are already sorted; the dates within `newTimes` fall within the range of `timeseries` dates; and that the initial `timeseries` entries are on the hour, every hour, we can find the difference between timeseries[0][0] date and newTimes[0] in hours. This is the initial offset required to start the bubble sort approach (more like just a standard loop and slice as discussed in the comments above). This uses the `Moment.js` library.

Code presented below, please feel free to suggest changes:

```
var firstEvent = moment(newTimes[0]);
var firstTime = moment(timeseries[0][0]) ;
var offset = firstEvent.diff(firstTime, 'hours') - 1; 


for (var i = offset; i < timeseries.length;i++) { 
    while (newTimes.length > 0 && typeof moment(timeseries[i+1]) !== "undefined" && moment(newTimes[0])  > moment(timeseries[i][0]) && moment(newTimes[0])  < moment(timeseries[i+1][0])) {
        var newElement = timeseries[i].slice(0);
        newElement[0] = moment(newTimes[0]).toDate();
        timeseries.splice(i+1, 0, newElement);
        newTimes.splice(0,1);
        i++;
    } 
}
```

Importantly, this copes with the edge case when there are two or more entries in the `newTimes` array that all fall within within just one `timeseries` entry, for example:

```
var timeseries = [
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 3, 2],
    [Tue Dec 31 2013 01:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 1.2, 3]
]

var newTimes = [
    Tue Dec 31 2013 00:13:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), 
    Tue Dec 31 2013 00:16:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
]
```